# Import Logics App HTTP request endpoint in API management service in Azure

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I want to import/ associate my Logics App HTTP request trigger endpoint into API management service; I can't find the URL endpoint when I create an API in API management create form.
Please advise

[image: Logics App endpoint]

[image: API Management]

Comment: The logic app and the azure api management need to be in the same subscription. Can you please confirm if that is the case?

Comment: @theabodeofcode- Yes. They both are in the same subscription package.

Comment: I am not facing this problem at all, I tried creating logic apps in different locations but they still show up as they are in same subscription
Can you try by adding the url as a backend url in a blank api?

Comment: @theabodeofcode- Good point. I will give a try on that. What are the differents among these components,Blank API and Logics API?

Comment: When you use the logic apps option, the API management does internal mapping for setting the backend url. In case of Blank API you will have to set these values yourself

Comment: @theabodeofcode -I gave a try on the Blank API; indeed, it is required of tedious stuff to do. Especially, the backend mapping part. A weird thing has happened here, I managed to add one of the Logics Apps from the Logics App's creat screen, now, I can't see the list anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209525/discussion-between-david-and-theabodeofcode).